# Nested Attribute Strong Parameters only update foreign key, created_at and updated_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem related to nested attribution and strong parameters on Rails 4. I have a `Property` model, nested with a `Status` model but each Property only `has_one` Status. The problem is that when I add/update a property, the property is updated but not the status. Looking at the server logs, it seems that Rails has created the status model but decided to only add/edit the `property_id` (Foreign key), `created_at` and `updated_at` field. Here is the log to make the point:

```
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "statuses" ("created_at", "property_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 11 Jan 2014 16:03:21 UTC +00:00], ["property_id", 9], ["updated_at", Sat, 11 Jan 2014 16:03:21 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.4ms)  commit transaction
```

Notes there is no Unpermitted... message there.

I am quite sure it is not a problem related to model as I have tried to do the same operations in Console and the `property.save` works. That points me to the direction of something related to the strong parameters.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:
**models/property.rb**

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :status
end
```

**controllers/properties_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    @property.build_status
    if @property.save
      redirect_to @property, :notice => "Property created successfully."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end
  private
  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:name,
      :address_line1, :address_line2, :address_city, :address_county, :address_postcode,
      :structure_Notes,
      status_attributes: [:id, :letting_start_date, :process, :comission, :check_in_date,     :check_out_date, :notes] )
  end
```

Thank you for reading! :)

Update:

The params past to the server included data:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cotr1JZPxPEKga4QbGiFMrEgM5D+UpAzZxEImW5iJvc=", "property"=>{"name"=>"Test Status Again", "address_line1"=>"", "address_line2"=>"", "address_city"=>"", "address_county"=>"", "address_postcode"=>"", "status_attributes"=>{"letting_start_date"=>"2013-01-01", "process"=>"Promoting", "commission"=>"", "check_in_date"=>"", "check_out_date"=>"", "notes"=>"fgjkhsdfkjgh sfjgh sdfhg lskdg"}}, "commit"=>"Create Property"}
```

Comment: What do the params look like that are being passed into the controller?  You'd find these in the logs.

Comment: The data are included in the params. I will update that in the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found out why it doesn't work.

If you look at the Controller:

```
def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    @property.build_status
    if @property.save
      redirect_to @property, :notice => "Property created successfully."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

The attribute value is assigned well before the status object is built. As a result, there's no status value assigned when `property` get saved.

Here's the new code:

```
    @property = Property.new
    @property.build_status
    @property.assign_attributes(property_params)
```

Hope this will help someone in the future... Big thanks for everyone who have seen and tried to solve this problem!